# Having issues with setting headers for API request, setting to accept 'application/json', but sending 'application/json, text/plain, */*'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-headers, ionic4

I am trying to set the headers of the get request to have a Bearer token in it, and some of my calls are not be formulated correctly, am I am unsure of where the breakdown may be occuring.

I have an Angular/Ionic app that uses an API service to make my calls.

In my api.service.ts, I get/set my Bearer token like this:

```js
constructor(
  private http: HttpClient,
  private storage: Storage
) {
  this.storage.get('token').then( k => {
    const _headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + k
    }
    console.log(k); //I can see my token in the console
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders(_headers);
  });
}
```

And then for a API call, I typically have a function like:

```
getUser() {
  return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/v1/users', { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
    map(response => {
      return response;
    })
  );
}
```

Within my home.page.ts, I call getUser from my API service like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getUser().subscribe(response => {
      this.user = response;
  });
}
```

When my app loads to it's first screen, none of the API calls are passing the Authorization headers, and when I inspect the call, it shows the Requested Headers with:

`Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*`

However, I set it only accept `'application/json'` in my headers.

Now, if I navigate to another tab in my app, each of the subsequent API calls all have the Authorization header.

My backend API is using PHP and all headers are set with:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Additionally, if I move the API services call out of the `ngOnInit` and into the `ionViewWillEnter` event, then the Authorization headers are appearing in my calls.

I even tried using a HTTP_INTERCEPTOR for the calls, and it resulted with the same outcome.

Do I have something misconfigured on my server side, or is something getting loaded out of sequence in the app that is causing the Authorization headers not to be set on my initial screen?

Comment: could you provide a piece of code where `getUser()` is called. I believe it is done just before your `.then` callback is executed

Comment: @Andrei - yes, I have updated the original post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting token from storage asynchroniously. Because of that your headers are not yet created at the moment you are trying to accesss them. what I can offer you is to store headers stream (or promise) instead, and use this async item later in request

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.headers = from(this.storage.get('token').then( k => new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + k
      }));
    // note: here this.headers is not headers, but a rxjs stream containing headers (you can store just promise if you like it better and then use it as a promise api);
  }
```

```
getUser() {
    return this.headers.pipe(
      switchMap((headers) => this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + '/v1/users, { headers })))
    );
  }
```

version with promise, just FYI:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.headers = this.storage.get('token').then( k => new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + k
      });
  }
```

```
async getUser() {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + '/v1/users, { headers: await this.headers }))
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andrei - your method had me rethink the async issues and how I could refactor my Interceptor code to work better.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to the HTTP Interceptor route after thinking through the Async issue that @Andrei had mentioned. I updated the Interceptor to this:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return from(this.storage.get("token")).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {

        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token) });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
```

And now all of the headers are being sent correctly.

Comment: nice. even better in this case